# Require password to login to Nexus 7

Tags: security, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

The default behavior in the Nexus 7 Image is to log straight in to the default user's desktop, bypassing the lightdm greeter. This seems like an acceptable behavior for testing the core but it's clearly insecure.

I've changed the default password and would like lightdm to actually require the password to be entered, rather than just having a button that says "login". I've turned automatic login on and off in System Settings → User Accounts but this doesn't help.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

**About the Passwords...**

Eventually the image will be just like any other desktop where you are prompted for a user/password, timezone, etc. It's being worked on.

**Disabling Autologin**

Edit (with sudo) /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf and comment out (with a #) the line that says

> autologin-user=ubuntu

Like this:

> #autologin-user=ubuntu

Then reboot or restart lightdm.

Also [please file a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-nexus7/+filebug) on this, I think the behavior should be consistent when you change those system settings.